# Robocopy | My data backup batch no longer works because of the new version, why? what did microsoft do?

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

Recently, I noticed a backup problem.
The new directories are well copied in the destination directory(s) but not the new files that go with them!
The problem is that there is obviously no error message in log file generated, the copy is done as if everything works correctly, it's extremely annoying.

Not having changed anything in my backup scripts, I noticed that the Robocopy command was updated by Microsoft on September 16, 2020 (**[KB4577069](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4577069/windows-10-update-kb4577069)**)

I checked the syntax with what I already have in my scripts and I don't see any particular change, so I don't understand the reason of this bug.

Extract from my script (batch file) :

```
start /wait /min Robocopy "G:\_PHOTOS" T:\ /E /EFSRAW /NP /XO /ETA /PURGE /R:0 /LOG+:!log1!
```

I tried /DEBUG with the command but it doesn't help me more.
I tried to replace /E and /PURGE by /MIR, no change ...

Extract from log file :

```
FindNextFile() Difference = + 1609h:48m:18.0395678s G:\Photo\_2020\Avril\20200421_162835.jpg
                       0 ----------D--  \\?\G:\photo\_2020\Decembre\
                       9 ----------D--  \\?\G:\photo\_2020\Decembre\Noel\
      Nouveau fichier          5.1 m -A-----------  IMG_3676.JPG
      Nouveau fichier          5.1 m -A-----------  IMG_3686.JPG
      Nouveau fichier          5.5 m -A-----------  IMG_3688.JPG
      Nouveau fichier          5.5 m -A-----------  IMG_3689.JPG
      Nouveau fichier          5.4 m -A-----------  IMG_3690.JPG
      Nouveau fichier          5.5 m -A-----------  IMG_3691.JPG
      Nouveau fichier          5.3 m -A-----------  IMG_3693.JPG
      Nouveau fichier          5.3 m -A-----------  IMG_3694.JPG
      Nouveau fichier          5.7 m -A-----------  IMG_3700.JPG
```

Does somes can help me please to fix this issue ?

Best Regards.

Comment: In order to assist you with a specific issue, we need to be able to reproduce it. In order to do that you need to provide a [mcve] of the code which produces the exact issue you require assistance with. Along side that, we also need to be able to recreate the same file structure and environment required for the problem to manifest itself. Until your question has been edited to include such things, we will be unable to assist you with your issue, and your question will be closed as off topic. Please read [ask], and its linked pages, to get an idea of how best to use this site.

Comment: Did you read my previous comment at all, before modifying your question content? Which parts of it did you fail to understand? Also, as you're indicated that this is not your entire batch script, I doubt very much that you should be using, `start` at all, never mind with the `/wait` and/or `/min` options! Additionally, you should, for safety, also doublequote, `!log1!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that switch `/EFSRAW` is frustrating this task, but it might work well if we remove it,

```
ROBOCOPY "G:\_PHOTOS" T:\ /E /NP /XO /ETA /PURGE /R:0
```

Comment: I remove it, it sounds good...We dunno, a new bug from Microsoft. I think a lot of people will end up with backup problems because of this lousy bug.